# push logs in S3 to dynamoDB continuously

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis-firehose

we have our application logs pumped to S3 via Kinesis Firehose. we want this data to also flow to DynamoDB so that we can efficiently query the data to be presented in web UI (Ember app). need for this is so that users are able to filter and sort the data and so on. basically to support querying abilities via web UI.

i looked into AWS Data pipeline. this is reliable but more tuned to one time imports or scheduled imports. we want the flow of data from s3 to dynamoDB to be continuous.

what other choices are out there to achieve this? moving data from S3 to dynamoDB isn't a very unique requirement. so how have you solved this problem?

Is an S3 event triggered lambda an option? if yes, then how to make this lambda fault tolerant?

Comment: Have you tried AWS Athena? It lets you do SQL-like queries on S3 data.

Comment: @dashmug yes. it was our first choice. we paritioned the data in s3 and used Athena on top of it. success (in terms of scale, cost) of using Athena is determined by partitioning strategy. in our use case we estimated that we would hit the limits on partitions and hence wouldn't be feasible/cost-effective.

Answer (score 2):

**For Full Text Querying**

You can design your solution as follows for better querying using AWS Elasticsearch as the destination for rich querying.

- Setup Kinesis Firehouse Destination to Amazon Elastic Search. This will allow you to do full text querying from your Web UI.
- You can choose to either back up failed records only or all records. If you choose all records, Kinesis Firehose backs up all incoming source data to your S3 bucket concurrently with data delivery to [Amazon Elasticsearch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-destination.html).

**For Basic Querying**

If you plan to use DynamoDB to store the metadata of logs its better to configure S3 Trigger to Lambda which will retrieve the file and update the metadata to DynamoDB.

Comment: thanks. this looks promising. but isn't this expensive since it requires it's own cluster per domain? how would you weigh this with dynamoDB approach?

Answer (score 0):

> Is an S3 event triggered lambda an option?

This is definitely an option.  You can create a [PutObject event](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-s3) on your S3 bucket and have it call your Lambda function, which will invoke it **asynchronously**.

> if yes, then how to make this lambda fault tolerant?

By default, asynchronous invocations will [retry twice upon failure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html). To ensure fault-tolerance beyond the two retries, you can use [Dead Letter Queues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dlq.html) and send the failed events to an SQS queue or SNS topic to be handled at a later time.